# How to compare string and substring

Tags: excel, substring, vba

I kind of stuck on this case. My issue is I want to find a "similar" text and replace it with the right one.

Example :

I have a text : ab123

And i have a set of text :
- abc123
- bds983
- fgh2315
- lol922

I need to make my text replaced with the most similar text in my set of text, in  this case ab123 will become abc123

I have tried compare it using InStr(), but it will only works only if the typo is on the left or on the right, it will not work if the typo is on the middle.

Here's the code

```
For i = 2 to LastRow
If (InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, Cells (3, 4).Value)) <> 0 Then
Cells(3, 4).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
End If
Next i
```

Thanks for your attention

Randy

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 0):

You basically will want to add your range of "correct" options to your custom dictionary, then run a spellcheck where you have unchecked "ignore numbers," You can either set it to automatically accept everything it finds or require the user to click OK to confirm it, then either leave them in the dictionary or clear them out.

You could go into a bunch of logic where you write a partial matching algorithm for the longest common subsequence, but you are basically creating a spellchecker with what you have described, and you already have one. So if this doesn't take care of what you need, then please expand on why not. :-)

If your list of "words" changes frequently then you will need to add them to the dictionary each time you spellcheck. If it doesn't, and it is a shortish list, you can just highlight it, spellcheck it and add them all.

For this to work you will need to go into file/options proofing and uncheck the option to ignore words with numbers.

There are quite a few hits on modifying custom dictionaries so I won't rehash the code if you need to do this in VBA. Pick your favorite and go with it, then post here if you run into issues. (I'd start a new thread with questions specific to what you run into.)

```
Application.SpellingOptions.IgnoreMixedDigits = False'how you ensure words with numbers get 
'spell checked if you end up coding it in VBA
```

Good luck!